# Traffic data is displayed above drawn shapes (polylines) in Android Google Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, z-index, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm drawing route with polylines and traffic data is displayed above route so route is partially  hidden by traffic lines.

**UPDATE**
I create issue on [gmap-api-issues](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6468) and attached sample source code there (you only need to add your Google Maps API key to AndroidManifest.xml). Please "star" these issue to attract Google developers attention.

Comment: How about disabling the traffic layer ?

Comment: @Morendo Application users need to view traffic layer. The whole question is about how to show route above traffic.

Comment: @mixel Any working solution about it for now? Stumbled with the same issue.

Comment: @grub See update. No working solution, but Google acknowledged my issue as a bug on Sep 21.

Comment: Has the issue been solved or not ?

Comment: @Kedarnath I do not know. You can download sample project attached to issue and try to build and test it with latest Google Maps SDK.

Comment: its still not resolved :)

Comment: @mixel, has it solved? I am getting same problem like you.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the Z index of your polyline the higher the value the higher your layout

```
 GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 // Add a thin red line from London to New York.
 Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));
     .zIndex(POLYLINE_Z_INDEX)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html

Comment: I can also confirm that it is not working - I even tried calling zIndex(Float.MAX_VALUE) and it the PolyLine still appears under the traffic information.